# How to make image under div unclickable using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sugarcrm

This is my code

```
<div id="companyLogo">
    <a href="index.php?module=Home&amp;action=index" border="0">
        <img src="themes/default/images/company_logo.png?v=hQ67b-0XWvvSENtpYeZcIw&amp;logo_md5=1d2df0902a895af3e05dbc7c4e6758eb" alt="Company logo" border="0" height="15" width="141">
    </a>
</div>
```

Now, I want to disable this logo. I am using this jquery code

```
var o = document.getElementById('companyLogo');
o.onmouseover = function() {
    var a = this.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (x in a) {
        a[x].onclick = function() { return false; };
    }
};
```

but, it's not working. Now this image in header div. So, if I replace companyLogo id name of image with the header div, then it works, but it makes whole header div section  unclickable. I want only few div's unclickable. So, may I know how to achieve that?

Comment: Why are you nesting handlers? BTW, there is no DIV inside `#companyLogo`

Comment: That is not jquery ...

Comment: Why do you have an `<a>` if it shouldn't be clickable? What else do you do with anchors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works except you have to change `div` to `a`.

check this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/01twspsL/)

Updated code

```
var o = document.getElementById('companyLogo');
o.onmouseover = function() {
    var a = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (x in a) {
        a[x].onclick = function() { return false; };
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Cerlin, Well I didn't know that, but I knew now. Thank you and stackoverflow....its making me better everyday. Thank you all for taking your valuable time out to help me.

Answer (score 2):

User this:

```
$('#companyLogo a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you timber, your solution is also working. But I can't give correct tag to everyone who gives me correct solution. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#companyLogo a").attr("href", "#");
```